# Better regex search for visual studios?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, ide

The regex on visual studios is weird and non standard.

Is there an extension i can use to give me better regex? If not then what IDE or text editor can i use to find/replace text in a directory. I dont want to replace all at once, just find, look and decide to hit next or replace/next

Comment: Related: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/458656/modify-visual-studio-find-and-replace-to-accept-other-non-ms-text-matching-engines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an external editor like Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download). Most will have a "Find In Files" menu option that will search your solution's files and most accept regular expressions as well.

E.g. in Notepad++

1. Go to Search > Find In Files...
2. Set the Directory to wherever your solution or project is
3. Make sure the Search Mode is set to Regular Expression